# Medical images, computing correlation of slices for a specific planes

Tags: image-processing, filtering, nifti

What quantitative measure should I use to compute on stacked 2D images (slices of MR images) that should be specific to the plane (axial, saggital or coronal)? like a correlation between the slices that is specific to the image plane slices are in, and the correlation varies from plane to plane?

Comment: I think you might wanna explain the situation and the goal in more detail. prefer to show instead of tell.

Comment: The question is not specific enough. There are probably too few specialists in the world who can understand it from those few lines.